# Looping in JQuery. Repeating an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a JQuery snippet to loop around and keep displaying the messages in the array. This is what I have so far and it works, it just won't loop round after once even though I have the counter set to 100.

What am I doing wrong? What would be best practice and why?

Thanks in advance

```
function popMessage() {
    $('#message').html(messages.pop()).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500, popMessage);
};

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var messages = [
        "Message 1",
        "Message 2",
        "Message 3",
        "Message 4",
    ].reverse();


    $('#message').hide();
    popMessage();
}
```

Comment: @SaadAlothman [please be careful with references to w3schools](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: The logic here isn't going to work, the for loop finishes near immediately, then after the 4th time through the array will be empty.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I need to do a bit more reading on arrays but your help is appreciated. Good reference @Pointy ! Insightful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are removing all the elements but one from the array. Just push it to the beginning for cycle to repeat. Also you can remove that loop it is unnecessary anyways you are invoking the method as callback for fadeOut. Try:

```
function popMessage() 
{   
    var msg = messages.pop();
    messages.unshift(msg);
    //You can avoid reversing of array and use the below script as well.
    //var msg = messages.shift();
    //messages.push(msg);
    $('#message').html(msg).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500, popMessage);
};
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z6rwr/)**

Comment: @user3072619 You dont need that loop.

Comment: Thank you for your really detailed reply! I can't believe I overlooked this one. Thanks again!